Change network location to another domain controller
I have two domain controllers dc1 and dc2. whenever i type \domainame in my domain joined client it points out to the network share that belongs to dc1.
how can I change the location from dc1 to dc2 so that whenever i type my domain name in the network location it points towards dc2 network share

\\DC2\Sharename or \\DC2

or maybe you can use Dfs where the name keep the same but the destination can be replaced

@GregAskew: Yeah but that's no longer \\domainname, now it's just \\servername, which I believe would defeat the point of OP's usage of \\domainname (which normally leads you to "any working DC")...

I that case DNS Mnemonics could be used to (not) register some DNS records for DC1, but hard to know with no information or context.
